# Solving a finite linear recurrence relation of the form $s_{i+1}=\alpha s_i + \beta$

Tags: recurrence-relations, lambert-w

Suppose I have a sequence $s_0, s_1,...,s_N$, where $N$ is a finite number. This sequence obeys the recurrence relation $s_{i+1}=\alpha s_i+\beta$. The sequence also satisfies the following conditions: $s_0=0$, $s_1=r_{min}$ , and $s_N=r_{max}$ , where both $r_{min}$ and $r_{max}$ are known quantities. Given the aforementioned conditions, obviously $\beta=r_{min}$. However, I'm not quite sure how to go about solving for $\alpha$ or $s_i$. I was given the hint that the solution involves a Lambert $W$ function, but otherwise I'm in the dark. If anyone could potentially point me in the right direction, I would be eternally grateful!

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Have you tried calculating the next few values of $s_i$, e.g., $s_2$, $s_3$, etc., to determine if you can see a pattern you can use? Also, FYI, the recurrence relation is a relatively simple example of a [Linear difference equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_difference_equation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $S_1=aS_0+b$ and $S_2=a^2S_0+ab$.

$S_{i+1}=aS_i+b~~~~(1)$, then $S_{i+2}=aS_{i+1}+b~~~~(2)$. Subtract (1) from (2}
to get $$S_{i+2}-S_{i+1}=a (S_{i+1}-S_i)\implies T_{i+1}=aT_{i}\implies T_i=ca^i~~~(GP)$$
Further we have $$S_{i+1}-S_i=ca^i,~ c=(S_1-S_0)=(a-1)S_0+b$$
By telescoping, we get $$S_{k}-S_1=c[a+a^2+a^3+....a^{k-1}]=ac\frac{a^{k-1}-1}{a-1}$$
Finally, we get $$S_k=ac\frac{a^{k-1}-1}{a-1}+aS_0+b,~~~ c=(a-1)S_0+b$$

Comment: First off, thanks so much for the response. Cleared things up for me immensely. Given the conditions $S_0=0$, $S_1=b=r_{min}$, and $S_N=r_{max}$, I was able to take your result and obtain the following equation: $\frac{r_{max}}{r_{min}}-1=\frac{a^N-a}{a-1}$. I tried plugging this equation into Mathematica (free version) and it aborted the calculation because computing the solution exceeded its time limit. So I was wondering: do you have any suggestions as to how to go about making progress with this equation? Thank you in advance and once again :)

Comment: Very nice to know your response to my solution.